# Can't get MetaMask accounts to respond correctly

Tags: web3-providers

here is what I'm working on.
Ganache is running on `127.0.0.1:7545`
in my VSC, I ran the command `truffle migrate --reset`
in MetaMask, I choose to add new network with the RPC url: `HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545`, `chainID 1337.`

when I ran `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)`
it returns empty.

Comment: What is the web3 provider? It should be `https://127.0.01:7545`.

Comment: shouldn't it be HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545, which is the one shown in ganache rpc server?

Comment: Yes, Everything Ganache shows should be the provider.

Comment: yes , so i assume i have entered all the correct information to add a new server on metamask. so any idea why I'm not able to get the address when I run the command web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)

Comment: Check it: First import an account by `.add()` method try `web3.eth.getAccounts()` again.

Comment: problem solved. Going through metamask doc, I had to use `ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });`